# How to create triggers in Data Grip?

Tags: mysql, triggers, datagrip

I want to create triggers in my table.I am using Data Grip as an interface to connect to my database.I googled around and the documentation said that it had something like a "Generate" drop down list which has something like function and procedures templates available for creation.But I get no such drop down list and even when I go to the new option after right clicking a table,I don't get an option for functions or procedures.
I am using DataGrip 2017.1.2 and a MySQL data source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative to @Andrew 's answer (since 2016.3 or .2), you can:

- Open database console
- Press Alt+Ins (Cmd+N on Mac)
- "Generate" menu will pop up
- Select "Trigger"
- A "live template" will start
- Type trigger name...Enter
- Type table name...Enter
- ...
- Execute resulting script with Ctrl+Enter

Answer (score 3):

If nothing else, you could begin writing a CREATE TRIGGER statement and let DataGrip's code completion help you along the way.

In DataGrip, either **Open Console** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>), or right-click your table name and choose **New > Console File**, to open a window where you can begin typing "CREATE TRIGGER", and go from there.

The [*23.3 Using Triggers* page in the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) and its *23.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples* linked page are useful references.